# Convert Markdown table from SAP to Excel?

Tags: power-automate, sap-erp, o365-flow

I have a text table in a .txt file in near-markdown type layout on a daily SAP export and emailed and intercepted by Power Automate, similar to this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|PLnt     |MRPCn|Material   |Material Description                    |Pln stock|Total stck|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|0201     |F4   |202011     |Hyaluronic Acid No. 43                  |       0 |        0 |
|0201     |F4   |202104     |Blue 40 NGSTE (Post)                    |      47 |       47 |
|0201     |F4   |202203     |Nitroglycerine 44                       |      49 |       49 |
```

By near-markdown, I mean that if I put this in the markdown converter online at tableconvert.com it mostly unpacks it into csv but leaves the dashed lines. I don't know what format it really is.

I need to use power-automate to intercept the email with the text file, convert it to a pretty excel, run scripts on that excel (eventually), and then send it on its way.

Is this SAP specific markdown format or is it some other standard?  Is there a non manual way to do this? Flow doesn't seem to have any built in methods that I can find. My current plan is to break the txt file into an array and loop through it using the | as a separator and to trim the spaces.

I know there is a way export and email excel SAP with ABAP, but unfortunately I don't have access to that option.

Comment: It's just an old SAP format, it's displayed in SAP GUI software as a [table with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXdz2.png). For the second part of your question, I can't answer.

Comment: Your approach to split up each line is plausible.  I've done so in UiPath and it very much works.  Good luck, you'll work through it.

Comment: Where exactly does that export come from? Perhaps you could talk to whoever wrote that report and negotiate a more useful export format. But that depends on how exactly the report was implemented. If it's an inhouse-developed program, then it might be possible to install the ABAP2XLSX library and rewrite the output part to generate a real excel table. Or if that's not an option, an ABAP programmer could implement a CSV export. If it's a program by SAP, then changing it might be unwise. But there might still be other export options in that program.